# Do we need to free memory in php?

Tags: php, memory, memory-management

Do we really need to free memory by objects we created? Or does PHP handle this by itself?

I've used `free()` in c, `delete` in c++ so far.

Comment: Short answer: no. Realistic answer: it depends. Actual answer: it's somewhat unclear what you're asking.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But I don't think its unclear. Like how we are creating object in c++ and deleting after its usage. As you said here it's not required. But I don't know why. Why don't we need same mechanism here then?

Comment: When you don't need an object anymore, of course you can delete it to free some memory (use `unset($object)` or `$object = null`), but you can't control the real memory usage of the PHP interpreter, nor do you have to do garbage collection by yourself.

Comment: Are you focussing on memory management overall or only for *objects*? Is your definition of "object" based on C or PHP or your own interpretation of what you mean by an "object"?

Comment: @deceze He meant an instance of a class. Nothing more

Comment: @djay Then I'm curious why objects in particular... :)

Answer (score 1):

No, we basically don't need to free memory up, as php does garbage collection automatically right after a script ends.

Comment: It also does while the script is running.

Answer (score 1):

You have no actual control over memory allocation in PHP. PHP allocates memory and frees memory as you create and destroy variables. So: no, you cannot free memory by hand and don't have to either.

Having said that, you have indirect control over the used memory by how many variables you have in scope at any one time/how much data those variables hold. If your script is running into memory issues, you need to optimise what you store where and when those variables are discarded, so PHP can free the associated memory.

For example, this will eat a large amount of memory:

```
$var = file_get_contents('really_large_file');
```

This on the other hand won't:

```
$fh = fopen('really_large_file', 'r');
$aFewBytes = fread($fh, 1024);
```

This is the way you "manage memory" in PHP. You decide what to do. To understand how much memory each operation requires you need some understanding of what's going on behind the scenes.